# C++ Properly split text on char

Tags: c++, vector, split, delimiter

I am quite new to C++ and i think i made a tiny mistake somewhere in this bit of code. I failed to spot it so far. I hope you can help me, and tell me how/where/why it is wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

The code:

```
std::vector<std::string> spliter(const std::string& s, char delimiter)
{
        std::vector<std::string> result;

        size_t start = 0;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i != std::string::npos; i = s.find(delimiter,start))
        {
            result.push_back( s.substr(start,i-start) );
            start = i+1;
        }
        iprintf("\x1b[2J");
        printf("\x1b[4;0HDone Splitting Text.");
        swiWaitForVBlank();
        return result;
}
```

Parameters given:
`s = "$ 00-000 SS ''Prologue'' CF N00-001 V 1 MP 20"`
delimiter = `' '` (a space)

Expected result:

```
result[0] = $
result[1] = 00-000
result[2] = SS
etc.
```

Current wrong result:

```
result[0] = 
result[1] = 
result[2] = 00-000
etc.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you see that the first time in your loop, you're pushing back `s.substr(0,0)`?

Comment: Wait, 'i' is not set before the first loop happens? Still, it does not explain the missing '$' char though.

Comment: Have you seen the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/701092) question? Your code looks a little similar.

Comment: @Smileynator `i` is set to `0` and `start` is set to `0`.  Perhaps you meant to set `i` initially to `s.find(delimiter,start)`.

Comment: It is quite confusing to me, i should have stuck with a normal for loop instead of trying something this fancy

Comment: You have `std::size_t i = 0` in your code.  That's the initial value for `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way to fix your algorithm:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> spliter(const std::string& s, char delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::string::size_type start = 0;
    auto pos = s.find(delimiter, 0);
    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        result.push_back(s.substr(start, pos - start));
        start = pos + 1;
        pos = s.find(delimiter, start);
    }

    if (start < s.length())
    {
        result.push_back(s.substr(start));
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%24221) of this algorithm giving the correct output for your test string.

Notice, that you could generalize this to work with a string as a delimiter rather than a single character just by changing the type of `splitter`'s second argument (and passing `" "` instead of `' '`, of course).

Comment: This one works perfectly! i had to change 'auto' to 'std::size_t' because of how my compiler works, but this is great! I will take some time to analyze what exactly gone wrong as Drew and vidit told me. Thanks again!

Comment: This i noticed, 'size_t' seems to function just as well! I find this way easier to read as well. Next time i will not use a for loop like that. It will just cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is in the loop.. You start from 0, and the first thing that you push is from 0 to 0.

```
    size_t start = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i != std::string::npos; i = s.find(delimiter,start))
    {
        result.push_back( s.substr(start,i-start) );
        start = i+1;
    }
```

instead if you start `i` from `s.find(delimiter, start)` it should work. [Example here..](http://ideone.com/KXEeH7)